# Recovering any deleted file using Inode value?

Tags: linux, inode

Please correct me If I'm wrong

Is possible to recover the deleted file if you have inode number of file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the file is held open by another process then you can recover the file by using the inode number.

```
find /path/to/check -inum 1023564 -exec cp {} recoveredfile \;
```

If the file not held open by another process then your out of luck with using the inode.